# TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined, even when body-parser is included

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, body-parser

i'm trying to learn mean stack, and i'm stuck with this piece of error `TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined` now i search over internet, and people said i must include body-parser and i've that in my server.js file, i must be doing something wrong, btw i do want to mention, strangely, there are no node_modules folder in my app, but until body-parser, everything was working fine, i do have express installed as global package[image] and here is my file `server.js`

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var db = mongojs('contactlist', ['contactlist']);
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/contactlist', function (req, res) {
    db.contactlist.find(function (err, docs) {
        console.log(docs);
        res.json(docs);
    });
});
app.post('/contactlist', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    db.contactlist.insert(res.body,function(err,doc){
        res.json(doc);
    });
});
app.listen(3000);
console.log('Server running on port 3000');
```

`index.html file`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Static Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="/js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/controllers/controller.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
        <h1>Contact List App</h1>
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Number</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="contact.name"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="contact.email"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="contact.number"></td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addContact()">Add</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="contact in contactlist">
                    <td>{{ contact.name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ contact.email }}</td>
                    <td>{{ contact.number }}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

`controller.js file`

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('AppCtrl',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){
    $http.get('/contactlist').success(function(response){
        console.log("I got the data");
        $scope.contactlist = response;
    });
    $scope.addContact = function(){
        $http.post('/contactlist',$scope.contact).success(function(response){
            console.log(response);
        });
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `req.body` and not `res.body`.

Additionally, you should make sure that you are sending the right `Content-Type` client-side. You have a JSON body parsing middleware added, but are you sending JSON POST requests or are you actually sending `application/x-www-url-encoded` POST requests instead (you can check by placing something like `console.log(req.headers['content-type'])` in your POST handler)?